# SQL Server 2008: Encrypting and compressing backups: Suggestions?

Tags: sql-server, backup

Greetings!

Anyone using Red gate (www.red-gate.com) or another third party tool to do this?

We use SQL 2008 Web Edition.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag as "sqlserver", not "sql" and "server". I don't want to have to filter out "sql".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Backup from Redgate works pretty well.  Its a bit on the expensive side though... I believe its $700 or $800 for the Pro version... which is what you'll need in order to do AES 256bit backups.

That being said, if the price isn't a problem for you... go ahead and download the free trial and test it out for yourself.

Comment: We went with redgate sql backup. Cut our backup time from 90 minutes to 12. Rocks!

Answer (score 2):

For us it was between [**RedGate's SQL Backup**](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/) and [**Quest's LiteSpeed**](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/) for compression and encryption.  We ended up going with LiteSpeed because others in our organization are already using it.  I have been VERY happy with LiteSpeed from Quest.  My sales rep has also been extremely helpful and flexible.  We use other RedGate products as well and I did benchmark SQL Backup against LiteSpeed.  While my benchmarking showed that each were very comparable in our environment, I do prefer the interface in LiteSpeed.  Seemed a bit cleaner and easier to get around.

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2008 has the native abilty to compress backups and when the database uses tranparent data encryption, the backup is also encrypted.  I wouldn't recommend using anything else at this point in time.  I have used red gate in the past (sql 2005).  It worked as advertised.  since you're on web edition I'd compare the price of the upgrade to the price of redgate and see which is more cost effective.

Comment: Encryption is only in SQL Enterprise... I am on web edition, as noted...

I believe the same is true for compression....

Comment: DOH! that's right- see my edit for the update

Answer (score 1):

We use Redgate SQL Backup 5 Pro at work, it is an excellent product.  We dont use encryption, although I will be recommending it shortly; we use the compression features and they work a treat.

We have a 70GB DB and was can compress this to about 11GB, and it is super fast.  It has feature where you can calculate the amount of compression you will get for a database.  With version 5 (version 6 has just been released but havent had a chance to play with it) you can easily see what schedules are set for backups, as well as other scheduled jobs in SQL Server, and also what jobs have failed.

I highly recommend it if you dont mind the price.

An alternative that I have read about is Quest Litespeed, havent looked into this but other people rate it and redgate as the best backup products for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the Red Gate Backup solution directly, but I've used their data compare product and found it rock solid.  I'll put my vote behind anything they sell.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having intermediate files & your biggest concern is PRICE you can use some opensource command line utilities like [gzip](http://www.gzip.org) or [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org)  & then use xp_cmdshell to compress your .BAK file after sql server has dumped it out.

In the same way, you can also use [gnugpg](http://www.gnupg.org/) to encrypt the backup after it's compressed.

I've used this before on price sensitive customers with success!

[Red Gate - SQL Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_backup/index_v2.htm) is also highly recommended and does an excellent job & has a much friendlier price point.

[Quest - Lightspeed](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/) is a great tool & does wonders on large databases in terms of compression/speed performance.  You pay for it though, but from experience pricing can be flexible, so  make sure you try to negotiate!